# AspNet.Security.Oauth.Spotify HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("spotify", "access_token") Returning a null token after second login+

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, oauth, identityserver4, spotify

When using the ASP.Net core 3.0 angular SPA individual account template, and the AspNet.Security.OAuth.Spotify nuget package. When A user logs in, I want to be able to get their spotify access token so I can preform actions on the user's behalf. However, when I call await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("spotify", "access_token"); the results returns null.

I've debugged a bit and saw the spotify tokens on second+ login in the options.Events.OnCreatingTicket event, but I guess the token is just not passed around past that? I'm not really sure anymore.

Startup.cs
ConfigureServices

```cs
services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddIdentityServerJwt()
                .AddSpotify("spotify", options =>
                {
                    options.ClientId = Configuration["SpotifySettings:ClientId"];
                    options.ClientSecret = Configuration["SpotifySettings:ClientSecret"];
                    options.CallbackPath = "/callback";
                    options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
                    options.SaveTokens = true;

                    String[] items = {
                        "playlist-read-private", "playlist-modify-public", "playlist-modify-private", "playlist-read-collaborative", "user-library-modify", "user-library-read", "user-read-email"
                    };
                    foreach (var item in items)
                    {
                        options.Scope.Add(item);
                    }

                    options.Events.OnRemoteFailure = (context) =>
                    {
                        // Handle failed login attempts here
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    };

                    options.Events.OnCreatingTicket = ctx =>
                    {
                        List<AuthenticationToken> tokens = ctx.Properties.GetTokens().ToList();

                        tokens.Add(new AuthenticationToken()
                        {
                            Name = "TicketCreated",
                            Value = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString()
                        });

                        ctx.Properties.StoreTokens(tokens);
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    };
                });
```

Code to try to retrieve token

```
            if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                return StatusCode(403);
            }

            var client = httpClientFactory.CreateClient("spotify");
            String spotifyToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("spotify", "access_token");

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", spotifyToken);

            var result = await client.GetAsync("v1/me/playlists");
```

I expected to get a spotify access_token that I can use to call the spotify api but spotifyToken just returns null.

Comment: What exactly does your question have to do with Identity server 4?

Comment: have you found an answer?

Answer (score 0):

On your callback handling method, in case of IdentityServer, on the ExternalController you read out the external identity of the temporary cookie - the result (in case of a success) holds both the Access & Refresh Token as Properties:

```
// read external identity from the temporary cookie
var result = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme);

if (result.Succeeded != true) 
   throw new Exception("External authentication error");

var tokens = result.Properties.GetTokens();
if (tokens?.Any() == true)
{
   _logger.LogDebug("External authentication success resulted in provided access tokens: \r\n {0}.", string.Join(",", tokens.Select(d => $"{d.Name}:{d.Value}")));
}
```